# Java making the code wait until Swing-Timer finished work

Tags: java, swing

I have a method where i start several amount of timers. They all do 
their work one after another (i simply increase the time to wait for 
each timer).

I need my programm to wait untill the last timer finished his work!
otherwise my programm will be recursivly called infinitely.

Here is my method:

```
public void doGameLogic(int cellID) {
    final ControllerHelper helper = new ControllerHelper();
    helper.setIndex(0);
    helper.setCellID(cellID);
    helper.setDecrement(false);
    helper.setFinished(true);

    if(actualGameState.getPlayersTurn() == ModelConstants.PLAYER_ONE) {
        helper.setActualCoinList(actualGameState.getCoinsPlayerOne());
    } else {
        helper.setActualCoinList(actualGameState.getCoinsPlayerTwo());
    }

    if(!(helper.getActualCoinList().get(helper.getCellID()) == 0)) {
        if(cellID > ((helper.getActualCoinList().size() / 2) - 1)) {
            helper.setIndex(cellID + 1);
        } else if(cellID < (helper.getActualCoinList().size() / 2)) {
            helper.setIndex(cellID - 1);
        }

        if(helper.getIndex() < (helper.getActualCoinList().size() / 2)) {
            helper.setDecrement(true);
        } else if(helper.getIndex() > ((helper.getActualCoinList().size() / 2) - 1)) {
            helper.setDecrement(false);
        }

        int coins = (helper.getActualCoinList().get(cellID));
        int time = 500;

        for(int i = 0; i < coins; i++) {
            Timer timer = new Timer(time, new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int tempDec = (helper.getActualCoinList().get(helper.getCellID()) - 1);
                    helper.getActualCoinList().remove(helper.getCellID());
                    helper.getActualCoinList().add(helper.getCellID(), tempDec);

                    if(helper.getIndex() > (helper.getActualCoinList().size() - 1)) {
                        helper.setIndex(((helper.getActualCoinList().size() / 2) - 1)); 
                        helper.setDecrement(true);
                    } else if(helper.getIndex() < 0) {
                        helper.setIndex((helper.getActualCoinList().size() / 2));
                        helper.setDecrement(false);
                    }

                    if(!helper.isDecrement()) {
                        int tempInc = (helper.getActualCoinList().get(helper.getIndex()) + 1);

                        helper.getActualCoinList().remove(helper.getIndex());
                        helper.getActualCoinList().add(helper.getIndex(), tempInc);

                        helper.setIndex(helper.getIndex() + 1);
                    } else {
                        int tempInc = (helper.getActualCoinList().get(helper.getIndex()) + 1);

                        helper.getActualCoinList().remove(helper.getIndex());
                        helper.getActualCoinList().add(helper.getIndex(), tempInc);

                        helper.setIndex(helper.getIndex() - 1);
                    }

                    setActualGameState(actualGameState);
                }
            });

            timer.setRepeats(false);
            timer.start();

            time += 1000;
        }

        if(!helper.isDecrement()) {
            helper.setIndex(helper.getIndex() - 1);
        } else {
            helper.setIndex(helper.getIndex() + 1);
        }

        if(!(helper.getActualCoinList().get(helper.getIndex()) < 2)) {
            doGameLogic(helper.getIndex());

            helper.setFinished(false);
        }

        if(helper.isFinished()) {
            if(this.actualGameState.getPlayersTurn() == ModelConstants.PLAYER_ONE) {
                this.actualGameState.setPlayersTurn(ModelConstants.PLAYER_TWO); 
            } else {
                this.actualGameState.setPlayersTurn(ModelConstants.PLAYER_ONE);
            }

            this.gameInfos.getGameHistory().putState(this.actualGameState);
            this.setActualGameState(this.actualGameState);
        }
    } else {

    }
}
```

obviously i cannot just make the thread wait as long as timer.isRunning()
is true because that will just freez my GUI or kill my programm.

Isnt there a way to make my program wait for the timers?

Comment: Stack overflow occurs when there is no more room on the heap for your recursive calls. Obviously, this recursive call is being called a lot of times, which is throwing the error.

Comment: In this example it just calls 3 times.... but anyway.. somehow i have to wait for the timers because it is senseless to continue with my program unless all timers are finished.

Comment: @user2663778 No, it calls it waaay more than 3 times. You don't get a Stack Overflow from calling a method just 3 times. You should put a `System.out.println("Calling doGameLogic(" + helper.getIndex() + ")");"` right before you call the `doGameLogic` method, in order to display how often it is called.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Its called over 4000 times. but that just happens because the program continues without waiting the timers to finish.
if(!(helper.getActualCoinList().get(helper.getIndex()) < 2)) {
            doGameLogic(helper.getIndex());

            helper.setFinished(false);
        }
this is the problem. the condition in the if-class is never false. it cannot be unless the programm waits for the timer to finish. Thats the reason why i somehow need to wait until all timers are finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

```
CountDownLatch lock = new CountDownLatch(coins);

for(int i = 0; i < coins; i++) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(time, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        /* All your actionlistener code here */

        lock.countDown(); //Signal to the CountDownLatch that this timer is finished
        }
    });

    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();

    time += 1000;
}

try {
    lock.await(); //Waits until the CountDownLatch has been counted down "coins" number of times
} catch (InteruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(); //or some more sophisticated handling of the error
}
```

However, are you executing `doGameLogic()` on the EDT? If you do like I described above on the EDT, the GUI will completely hang for several seconds. You should never wait for extensive amounts of time on the EDT. Tasks performed on the EDT should be small and quick, or the performance of the GUI will be disastrous.

If this is the case, you should redesign the threading strategy of your application so that all tasks that require extensive amounts of time due to waiting for something to complete are performed on non-EDT threads, and then they merely submit a small task to update the GUI when the time consuming part is finished.

**<EDIT>**

Check [this article](http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/7717) for a brief description of this problem. Look under the headling *"Never Delay the EDT"*

Basically, when it comes to time consuming tasks, the most common way is to use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to perform the time consuming computation / waiting / file operation / download etc.

The time consuming non-GUI-related task should be performed in the [doInBackground()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground%28%29) method, which is invoked on a non-EDT thread. Then subsequent necessary GUI updates can be performed in the [done()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) method which is invoked on the EDT when the background work has finished. For a full example, look in the small article I linked above.

**</EDIT>**

Comment: yes it is called on the EDT after i press a button. can i just put the code from doGameLogic into a SwingUtilities.invokeLater? would that work?

Comment: @user2663778 No, that would not help, since the code would still be executed on the EDT. I added an edit at the end of my post about this.

Comment: So a SwingWorker will solve it? putting my loop into the 'doInBackground()' and the rest into the done() method?

Comment: @user2663778 I guess you still need some way of waiting for the Timers to finish. So you'd need still need the CountDownLatch or some other means of synchronization within the doInBackground() method. This sounds a bit complex, and I guess things could be done in a better way, but I don't have a good enough understanding of what the loop is trying to perform and what the purpose of the timers is. The important thing is just to follow the ground rules **1)** `Never interact with GUI components on non-EDT threads` **2)** `Never perform time consuming tasks on the EDT thread`